# Editing custom fields for multiple entries at once

Tags: custom-fields

Is there any way to edit the same custom field for multiple entries at once?

Something like an entry equivalent of the field editor add-on.

[image: fieldeditor]

I know Zenbu has title/url editing available, just wondered if it was possible with custom fields?

Comment: Looks like the developer of Zenbu is bringing in custom field editing, too! Himitsu, currently in beta: https://twitter.com/zenbustudio/status/329674860546637825

Answer (score 1):

OK, not ideal, but as all my data was coming in from an XML feed, I created another CVS file with a column of unique fields (matching unique fields in my entries) and added the text that I wanted into another column.

I then imported all this via Datagrab add-on.

Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen one for the control panel, but it can certainly be done via Safecracker using a template visible only to logged in members of the appropriate member group.  Depending on the nature of the field(s) being edited and how many are being edited at once though, you can quickly run into some performance limitations.

Comment: Hmm, was hoping for a CP way. The only other way I'm thinking is an SQL query, although I'm not 100% confident on what I'm doing with that. At the moment I have an empty custom field that I want filled with the same value for around 2000 entries, and really don't want to go into each entry to fill it in!

Comment: Yeah, in particular if it's not an editing function you need on an ongoing basis and this will be a one-time update, then going the query route and inserting the value directly into the DB may be the simplest course, depending on the fieldtype in question.